# How to restore when activity is destroyed or paused?

Tags: android, savestate

Okay so im having a hard time saving the state of my activity so that when the activity is destroyed it can restore where the user last left off. Here is my source code. If anyone could look at it and tell me how i would save and restore is please it will be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code...

```
                public class DorothyTalk extends Activity{
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    int typeBar;
TextView text1;
EditText edit;
Button respond;
private String name;
private ProgressDialog progDialog;
@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.dorothydialog);

    text1 = (TextView)findViewById(com.fttech.da.R.id.dialog);
    edit = (EditText)findViewById(com.fttech.da.R.id.repsond);
    respond = (Button)findViewById(com.fttech.da.R.id.button01);

    Talk();

}

    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
switch(id) {
case 0:                      // Spinner
    progDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    progDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    progDialog.setProgress(100);

    return progDialog;
```

}
    return progDialog;
}
        public void  Talk(){

```
    text1.setText("Welcome what is your name?");

    respond.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            name = edit.getText().toString();
            new AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>(){

            @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            try {                 
             Thread.sleep(1000);             
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {                         
                e.printStackTrace();             
                    }            
                    return null;
            }
            @Override         
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {             
                    text1.setText("Nice to meet you "+name);
                    dismissDialog(typeBar);
                     }


                @Override        
        protected void onPreExecute() { 
            typeBar = 0;
        showDialog(typeBar);

        }

        }.execute((Void)null);

        }
    });
    }


    public void onBackPressed()
      {
        int i = Log.d("CDA", "onBackPressed Called");
        Context localContext = getApplicationContext();
        Intent localIntent = new Intent(localContext, mainMenu.class);
        startActivityForResult(localIntent, 0);

        return;




    }
```

How can i save and restore when activity is destroyed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to save your data before your activity is destroyed. You can test if it is going to be destroyed by using the isFinishing()

protected void onPause(){
if(isFinishing()){
 saveData();
}
}

then you neeed to reload your data onCreate()

Comment: Okay thanks that makes sense. So What would you recommend for me to save my data and then reload it.. Its kind of complex because the textview will be constantly changing and variables will be constantly added.. What would you recomment?

Comment: I would need to know what app you are building, but you can probably save your text to a file and reload it onCreate... you can save all your conversation into a log file and reload it.

Comment: It depends on what you want to do... writing to a file is simple look it up on the developer guide for examples. If you require anoter type of persistence, then make sure you use a proper persistence library... I would need to know more about your application to provide a more detailed anwser, here is a pointer http://www.slideshare.net/pohjus/android-6732335 it may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can try overiding

```
public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {

    //object returned here can always be recovered in getLaststNonConfigurationInstance()
    return something;
}
```

and use `getLastNonConfigurationInstance()` to get the state back.